# for vs while loop python

Tags: python

¡Hola! Soy nuevo en python y sageMath y estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio con mi compañero, el caso es que necesitamos una lista de cuadrados perfectos y he pensado que podría hacerlo de esta manera.

```
n =95        
squares=[]  
edges=[];
for i in range(int(sqrt(n)+1)):  
    squares.append(i*i)
```

Entonces leí que sería una buena idea usar el bucle while porque estoy iterando hasta que la condición int(sqrt(n)+1) deje de ser cierta lo cual tiene sentido, por lo tanto esto sería lo que creo que es el código equivalente.

```
n =95      
squares=[]  
edges=[]
i=0
root= int(sqrt(n)+1)
while i < root:  
    squares.append(i*i)
```

Sin embargo obtengo un error `Traceback (most recent call last)` en diferentes partes del código cada vez que lo ejecuto o tarda demasiado. Cualquier ayuda será apreciada ya que soy nuevo, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si lo que quieres es generar una lista de todos los cuadrados perfectos hasta `n`,
te basta con un `for`, por que iteramos sobre un `range(n)`
el rpimer error que se aprecia es que `cuadrados` no esta definido,lo que defines es `squares` con eso nos basta

```
squares = []
for i in range(n):
    squares.append(i*i)
```

se podria utilizar un `while` pero la estructura seria mas compleja:

```
i = 0 
squares = []
while i < n:
    squares.append(i*i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: vale lo que me faltaba era i+=1 que si lo hiciese con for no sería necesario añadirlo no?

Comment: no no lo seria,por que el `range(n)` lo hace por ti

Comment: muchas gracias @elweoncalvo